# Скрытие закрытых вопросов из ленты

Tags: предложение

Добавьте возможность скрытия закрытых вопросов в ленте. На данный момент их никак нельзя скрыть ни используя пользовательский фильтр, ни какими-либо другими стандартными средствами. На худой конец, добавьте какой-либо HTML-аттрибут или класс к этим вопросам, чтоб их можно было скрывать пользовательским CSS.

[image: Текущий интерфейс добавления/создания пользовательского фильтра]

Comment: То есть, стандартное `closed:false` для вас не подходит?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ куда мне вбить сие, чтоб в моей ленте скрыть закрытые вопросы? Это-же относится и к пользовательским фильтрам - для них куда это вбивать? Если предлагаете руками на каждый клик дописывать это в поиск, то "да" - это не подходит.

Comment: Сбоку "Создать пользовательский фильтр", настраиваете его так, как хотите, добавляете туда нужные языки, и другие фильтры, сохраняете, и пользуетесь дальше им, ничего постоянно вводить не надо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ тыкните меня носом в прикреплённый скриншот - куда там тыкать, чтоб скрыть закрытые вопросы...

Comment: Хм, что-то я и правда попутал, в фильтры такое не подставляется, только поиск. Ну чтож, тогда вам с таким вопросом на английскую мету.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ думал что модераторы имеют какие-то более весомые/эффективные способы донести до руководства/разработчиков предложения, чем рядовой пользователь.

Comment: Модераторы также, как и все остальные, идут на англ. сайт, и пишут туда все баг репорты и пожелания. Поэтому, хотите чет предложить, лучше писать на большой СО.

Comment: Думаю с текущим вопросам надо не на этой мете писать, а на area57 или где там принимают заявки на фичи... ТУТ нет никого из разрабов, кто делает функциональность......

Comment: .. А в целом, всякие фичи замучаешься тут ждать. Проще самому что-то сделать. Например через tempermonkey.. Я так и сделал давным давно - реализовал там себе фичи, которые мне необходимы

Comment: @АлексейШиманский скорее всего придётся своё что-то пилить...

Comment: @XelaNimed в поисковой строке `closed:no` и всё.

Comment: @Зонтик да не нужна мне поисковая строка! Мне нужны отслеживаемые метки и пользовательские фильтры!

Comment: Можно через JS фильтровать.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не на area51, а на [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) или [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com). Area51 - для создания новых сайтов.